# Swap zeros and ones in an Eigen::Matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have some image data stored in an Eigen Matrix. This is a greyscale image, composed of only black and white pixels, as either `0` or `255`.

What I need to do is swap these values, so that every black pixel becomes white, and vice versa.

in opencv, I can do this with the `bitwise_not` function. Does Eigen have a similar thing?

The Image class is:

```
template <typename T>
class Image : public Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>
{
  public:

    /// Pixel data type
    using Tpixel = T;

    /// Full internal type
    using Base = Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>;


    /**
     * @brief Default constructor
     * @note This create an empty image
     */
    inline Image()
    {
      Base::resize( 0, 0 );
    }
}
```

I have:

`Image<unsigned char> imageMask;`

Which is filled with the pixel data.

I now need to swap the black and white values.

Comment: `M = 255-M.array();` could work. Please post a [mre] for a more detailed answer.

Comment: This also works and generates good code: `matrix.unaryExpr(std::bit_not<Matrix::Scalar>{})`. Compile with `-O3` to let the compiler vectorize the whole thing